# How do I marshal wchar_t* from C++ to C# as an out parameter or return value?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, interop, marshalling

I have tried to do this in many ways, but none is working. Does anyone have a correct example for this? I just want to move the `wchar_t*` value from a function to the C# level.

Comment: That's ambiguous.  You'll need to post the C++ function declaration and describe how the argument is used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't as difficult as you think it is... What is `wchar_t*`? What value does that type typically represent? A string. It's the equivalent to the `LPWSTR` type defined in `windows.h`.

So, you marshal it as a `string` type. However, since it's an `out` parameter (or a return value), you'll need to use the [`StringBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) on the C# end, rather than the `string` type.

The P/Invoke syntax would look something like this:

```
[DllImport("MyLib.dll")]
public static extern void MyFunction(StringBuilder str);
```

And to use it, you first declare an instance of the `StringBuiler` class with the appropriate capacity, and then call the function:

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder(255);
MyFunction(myString);
```

Remember that the unmanaged C++ code must free the string in order to prevent a memory leak. It's the only one with access to the unmanaged memory area where the string was allocated.

Comment: A `wchar_t*` out parameter has raw type `wchar_t**`.  The caller-allocated approach used in your answer is better, but it doesn't match the question (usually these questions come up when it is not possible to change the C++ code).

Comment: @Ben: Yeah, I guess you're right. The question really doesn't have enough information, but I thought I'd try answering it anyway. People usually ignore my comment pleas for additional info. And since this is precisely what you do for a function like [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520.aspx) (with `LPTSTR` as an out param) I'm not sure why it doesn't work here.

Comment: The raw type of `GetWindowText` is `LPTSTR`, which makes it an "out" parameter of type `TCHAR`, at least according to COM naming conventions.  Which might or might not be want the OP is using.

Comment: @Ben: As I understand it, `LPTSTR` is typedef'ed to `LPWSTR`, which is typedef'ed to `WCHAR*`, which is typedef'ed to `wchar_t*`. I'm afraid I don't understand what the difference is. Are you saying that there's a special exception for the pre-defined Windows data types when determining the raw type?

Comment: No special exception, the "raw type" of an "out parameter" has one more level of indirection than the "parameter type".