# c# : how to convert c# string to c++ wstring and vice-versa

Tags: string, visual-c++, c#-4.0, wstring, widestring

c# code-

```
string s="おはよう";
```

I want to send s to c++ dll, as wstring..
how to convert string to wstring in c# ?

Comment: How do you plan to send this to c++ dll? Usually the p/invoke will do the conversion for you.

Comment: Then you'll be using p/invoke([DLLImport]) and it should just work.

Comment: thats not the issue, but how to convert string to wchar in C++

Comment: I don't think there's a way to marshal a C# string to a C++ `std::wstring`. You can marshal it as a `LPTStr` or possibly `LPWStr`, but those are simply arrays of characters. Show us the prototype of the function you want to call, and we can make recommendations. You might also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051097/return-a-stdwstring-from-c-into-c-sharp

Comment: Nice help @JimMischel, thanks. Is there any other way to do it, or vice versa

Answer (score 4):

A `std::wstring` is a C++ object, allocated by the C++ runtime and having an implementation-dependent internal format. You *might* be able to figure out how to create one of those in a C# program and pass it to the unmanaged C++ code, but doing so would be somewhat difficult and fraught with peril. Because the internal structure of a `std::wstring` is implementation dependent, any change to the C++ compiler or runtime libraries break your solution.

What you're trying to do is typically done by writing an interface layer in C++ that takes an `LPTStr` parameter, converts it to a `std::wstring`, and then calls the C++ function that you wanted to call. That is, if the function you want to call is declared as:

```
int Foo(std::wstring p);
```

You would write an interface function:

```
int FooCaller(LPTSTR p)
{
    std::wstring str = p;
    return Foo(str);
}
```

And you call `FooCaller` from your C# program.

In short, C# can't create and pass a `std::wstring`, so you use a translation layer.