# Loading a native C++ dll generated from MATLAB(Simulink) into Unity3d

Tags: c++, dll, unity-game-engine, native, simulink

I am a game developer working on a serious game. I have some data simulation taking place as a result of a MATLAB (Simulink) model, that was created by someone who left the team now. All this data simulation generates useful data and allows me to query and check variables when needed. I needed to build a game using this model. So I used the Simulink Code generator to generate the code for my model in C++. This is native C++ and is procedural. The volume of code is high for me to rewrite it, hence I am refraining from doing that. I need to use this code in Unity3d, the engine I am developing the game on.

Long story short. I need to load a native C++ dll (generated by Simulink) in Unity3d.

What I tried:

1. I tried using the Unity3d's native plugin API. I have pro version and it doesn't seem to detect the dll, and just throws exceptions. I am using the extern keyword to make the required variables public, still no luck.
2. I tried following this tutorial (http://blogs.abo.fi/alexeevpetr/2011/11/18/simplified-building-simulink-generated-c-code-in-visual-studio/) , but it throws errors and doesn't build, maybe that's because of the version of MATLAB.
3. I also considered using a wrapper, however that would imply me rewriting most of the code again.

Comment: I never tried this but it's my understanding that MATLAB provides `mex` as a wrapper between MATLAB runtime libraries and your compiler, as a consequence the compiled object generated with `mex` it's not only containing standard C++ but it's "your code + matlab libs" and it still needs MATLAB runtime libraries to run. Also there is probably a problem about licensing your code too, since only the user who buys MATLAB can run your code legally.

Comment: I am aware that MATLAB provides the mex, however when I open the project in VS2010, VS2010 doesn't say that the project is linked to any MATLAB files. MATLAB is licensed to run on my User account, so I am ignoring that.

Comment: Simulink Coder generates stand-alone code, it does not include links to any MATLAB libraries, so  @user2485710's comment is not relevant here.  What code generation target are you using? The only one that automatically generates a dll is the ertdll target in Embedded Coder.  Are you using that, or just standard Simulink Coder to generate C++ code, then compiling it to a dll yourself?

Comment: @PhilGoddard I can easily accept the fact that I'm wrong on this, but, if SL generates C++ code using whatever C++ standard ( no words on that from Mathworks apparently ), what is the point of `mex` ?

Comment: There's not enough space here to describe these in detail, but: mex (MATLAB executable) is the mechanism for compiling C/C++/Fortran code so that it can be called from MATLAB; MATLAB Coder is a tool to convert m-code (not Simulink) to C code that is completely independent of MATLAB; MATLAB Compiler is a tool to convert m-code (not Simulink) to an application that is wholly still dependent on the MATLAB Engine; Simulunk Coder is a tool to convert a Simulink model (not MATLAB) to C code that is independent of MATLAB or Simulink

Comment: I am using the **ertdll target in Embedded Coder**

Answer (score 1):

I've never used native dlls in Unity, but you could always try one of the several code bridging methods to call C++ code from C#, I guess. So how about writing a C++/CLI wrapper? It won't force you to rewrite anything. It gives managed access to your unmanaged code, and it's a useful technique to learn anyway.

Comment: C# can only be extended with C not with C++, also your answer is more like a comment.

Comment: Huh? what do you mean "extended with C"? You can write C++/CLI wrapper code and marshall your datatypes to consume in C# code, of course you can.

Comment: the FFI mechanics are based on C code, C# can communicate with any language that can be translate in C code, the "dll" that you generate and use, is basically a C library. there is nothing in the spec that tells you otherwise, even the experience from other languages using other FFI, also if you read all those examples carefully, there is nothing that is really C++-ish, there are a lot of really basic data structures and pointers, and that is an hint ...

Comment: But for someone who isn't worried about what's happening under the hood, you're reusing C++ code, whether the mechanics are C or not. My point is that he (or she) won't have to rewrite everything.

Comment: let's say that you can cheat on that, C is even part of the C++ standard, so you can say that without being trapped in conundrum, but my point is: be aware of that, and if you deal with some "real" C++ code like an `std::vector` be sure that you know what you are doing and how to port a C++ vector into C code.

Comment: I have generated both C as well as C++ codes using Simulink, both seem to be independent of MATLAB files, and I could choose C as the language, if we have a valid workaround with that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load your native plugin into Unity3D, even if it requires MATLAB libraries (Just make sure they're also in the plugins directory). I recently answered a similar question around this, as it can be fairly tricky to get right. I would suggest you check it out [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182352/writing-c-dlls-and-access-them-unity-3d/20184406#20184406), and modify your question with specific errors and problems you're having trying to loading the native code.

Comment: Technically this is true, but the "MATLAB libraries" essentially entail one huge runtime engine that the OP most likely isn't interested in shipping along with their product.

Answer (score 1):

From Geomorillo on U3d forums:

Before anything,
1) install Visual C++ Studio Express 2010 we need the sdk from .NET for compiling, (NOTE:Maybe you can use visual C# express instead for compiling because it require the .NET sdk but no sure )
2)You must setup matlab with the command "mbuild - setup", and choose the compiler Microsoft Visual C++ Studio Express 2010
3) you must have a function already created and saved to a ".m" file mine is called mycos.m here is its contents:

function a=mycos(b)
a=cosd(b);
end

where "a" is the return parameter and "b" the input parameter, it is important to know how many return parameter you have in this case 1 (see step 12)

4) use the "deploytool" command, a window should open, name the project "simplelibs" any name should do, choose a location c:\matlab\simplelib, choose in type .NET Assembly, OK 
5) After that new options int form of tabs should appear to the right of your window, the Build and Package Tabs.
In the Build tab you should add a class with the Add class option, it will automaticly was named Class1, but i changed it to Myclass, here you can add your functions to your class using Add files, i've added mycos.m
6) You should have noticed 3 buttons next to the project name, click the 3rd one with the shape of a nut, go to Settings a new window should appear, go to .NET tab and in the Microsoft Framework choose 3.5 to make sure you are using .net 3.5 for compiling(required for unity3d) 
7) we are ready to compile, do so with the 1st button, it should take a while....
8) After compiling without errors, the files are in the distrib folder inside your project path , open unity and create a new project. copy the 2 dlls into the root inside unity.
9) Locate de directory "dotnetbuilder" inside "c/.../matlab/../toolbox" copy or drag it all its contents to your unity project.

10) We need the a dll MWArray.dll because when compiling our libraries matlab wraps our function in an Array and it use its methods to access our functions im not gonna explain this, google it please, normally it can be found inside matlab installation dotnetbuilder/bin/win32/2.0/ but since you have copied it to unity dont copy again, when using this mwarray i found a bug with monodevelop in this library so i had to decompile it and fix the bug i've to recompile it again :) you you can download this file here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6716823/MWArray.dll and replace the one found inside unity project (do not!!! replace the original from matlab directory)

11) create a c# script and asign it to main camera or any object in scene
here is its contents

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays; // import from MWArray.dll
using simplelib;

public class myMatlab : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {
simplelib.Myclass g = new simplelib.Myclass();
Debug.Log(g.mycos(1,95).GetValue(0));
}
}

12) g.mycos(1,95); // remember when i said it wraps your function !!! the first parameter is the number of parameters returned from our matlab function in this case 1, the 95 is the parameter we want to send to our function, we get an array we can access it with .GetValue(0)

13) play and enjoy

This is an example with a simple function so i dont know if it will work with a more complex program

i hope this works for you