# wchar_t data being jumbled from unmanaged to managed

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

i have a managed GUI in C# and unmanaged DLL in C++.  i pass a struct by reference to the DLL function where it's populated.  the struct has several wchar_t elements and several strings.

inside the DLL all the data looks fine before returning to the GUI.  for example:

```
struct1->ch1 = 0x1234;
struct1->ch2 = 0x5678;
struct1->ch3 = 'ab';
struct1->ch4 = 'cd';
```

but when the struct is returned from the DLL the data is garbled.

```
struct1->ch1 == 0x0034
struct1->ch2 == 0x0012
struct1->ch3 == 0x0078
struct1->ch4 == 0x0056
```

the other string elements return fine.

the char data being populated are single bytes, so i know i can just use BYTE types, but i'd like figure this out.

i'm new to the managed/unmanaged relationship, so i'm not sure what's going on.  any ideas?

Comment: Try taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089214/how-do-i-marshal-wchar-t-from-c-to-c-sharp-as-an-out-parameter-or-return-valu) and its selected answer. It seems like wchar_t can't just be passed from managed to unmanaged code the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. Firstly, you can mark your whole struct as Unicode (so the `chars` will be interpreted as `wchar_t`) with:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct MyStruct { ... }
```

Alternately you can use a 16-bit int:

```
short ch1;
```

Or tell the marshaller what to do each item explicitly using:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] char ch1;
```