# PInvoke calling of function with wchar16_t parameters

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a .dll with C++ function which takes `const wchar16_t*` parameters.
I'm trying to import and use it in c# with string, char array, and char array with additional '\0' char but I got no result.
When I check it in original c++ program in debug mode it have additional '\0' char at the end. What exact type should I use?

P.s. I'm not 100% sure that problems arises because of these parameters.
I would very appreciate and give many points to rep if someone could kindly look into small projects I [attach](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bllqmxy3xp3ime/sof2.zip?dl=0) illustrating the problem. C++ program works fine (we getlogin response), but in c# project OnLoginResponseCallback is never fire.

What I do in C#

```
[DllImport("ActiveTickServerAPI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "?ATCreateLoginRequest@@YA_K_KPB_W1P6AX00PAU_ATLOGIN_RESPONSE@@@Z@Z", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern ulong ATCreateLoginRequest(ulong sessionId, string user, string pwd, ATLoginResponseCallback onLoginResponse);

 public delegate void ATLoginResponseCallback(ulong hSession, ulong hRequest, ATLOGINRESPONSE response);
        public delegate void ATRequestTimeoutCallback(ulong origRequest);
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
 lastRequest = ATCreateLoginRequest(hSession, userId, pw, OnLoginResponseCallback); 
                bool rc = ATSendRequest(hSession, lastRequest, 3000, OnRequestTimeoutCallback);
    }
 static void OnLoginResponseCallback(ulong hSession, ulong hRequest, ATLOGINRESPONSE response)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("!THIS SHOULD FIRE, but fire only timeout callback");
        }

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 public struct ATLOGINRESPONSE
    {
        public byte loginResponse;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 255)]
        public byte[] permissions;
        public ATTIME serverTime;
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ATTIME
{
    public ushort year;
    public ushort month;
    public ushort dayOfWeek;
    public ushort day;
    public ushort hour;
    public ushort minute;
    public ushort second;
    public ushort milliseconds;
}
```

in c++ it's work (getting login response). Here is function description from api docs:

```
ACTIVETICKSERVERAPI_API uint64_t ATCreateLoginRequest   (   uint64_t    session,
    const wchar16_t *   userid,
    const wchar16_t *   password,
    ATLoginResponseCallback     pCallback 
)
```

working struct from c++

```
typedef struct _ATLOGIN_RESPONSE
{
    ATLoginResponseType loginResponse;
    uint8_t permissions[255];
    ATTIME serverTime;
} ATLOGIN_RESPONSE, *LPATLOGIN_RESPONSE;

    typedef struct _ATTIME
{
    uint16_t year;
    uint16_t month;
    uint16_t dayOfWeek;
    uint16_t day;
    uint16_t hour;
    uint16_t minute;
    uint16_t second;
    uint16_t milliseconds;
} ATTIME, *LPATTIME;
```

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089416/696034 will give you an answer?

Comment: not my case, your link about out parameter.

Comment: That may be a typo in the post, but the null terminator is \0, not /0

Comment: yes it is, thank you

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in the question. It's going to be easy to answer I am sure, but who wants to download an external project?

Comment: I understand. But I can't 100% locate the problem. This is last hope for me.

Comment: I'm sure you are capable of showing the code that matters.

Comment: I will add code very soon, don't vote to close please. I will put that in a bounty in 2 days if no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your test project and immediately fixed the delegate declarations because they were wrong:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void ATSessionStatusChangeCallback(ulong hSession, byte statusTyp);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void ATLoginResponseCallback(ulong hSession, ulong hRequest, ref ATLOGINRESPONSE response);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void ATRequestTimeoutCallback(ulong origRequest);
```

First time I ran the program I got:

```
SessionStatus - Connected
request timeout
!THIS SHOULD FIRE
SessionStatus - Connected
!THIS SHOULD FIRE
```

Second and subsequent times I got:

```
SessionStatus - Connected
!THIS SHOULD FIRE
```

No timeout.  Why it behaved the way it did the first time is very hard to guess.  You probably need to wait with the ATSendRequest() until you get confirmation of a proper login, something like that.

But clearly fixing the delegates took care of the problem, you are now getting the proper hSession value in the callback.  It is not yet perfect, you need to ensure that they cannot be garbage collected.  Store them in a static variable:

```
static ATSessionStatusChangeCallback statusCallback;
....
    if (res == true) {
        statusCallback = new ATSessionStatusChangeCallback(OnSessionStatusChangeCallback);
        res = ATInitSession(sessionNumber, "activetick1.activetick.com",
                 "activetick2.activetick.com", 443, statusCallback, true);
    }
```

Do the same thing on the 2 other ones.

Comment: Thanks Hans, you are great! I will be able to award bounty in 5 hrs. Though it getting more complicated than I thought. Got some crazy values in time struct of this callback and loginDenied type response meaning user ATGUID is wrong though I just copied required values. It must be something with translating structs back and forths.. I should dig into that topic.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `ATLOGINRESPONSE` is almost certainly wrong.

```
public class ATLOGINRESPONSE
{
    public byte loginResponse;
    public byte[] permissions;
    public ATTIME serverTime;
}
```

By declaring it as a class, you ensure that it will be marshalled by reference. But you preclude it ever being marshalled by value. Which might be fine. Anyway, I think I'd prefer to declare as a struct.

Further, the first two parameters look wrong to me. The first is probably an enum and should be declared as such. The second is a byte array but you need to specify how to marshal it. Like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ATLOGINRESPONSE
{
    public ATLoginResponseType loginResponse; // you need to define the ATLoginResponseType enum
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 255)]
    public byte[] permissions;
    public ATTIME serverTime;
}
```

We don't know whether or not `ATTIME` is declared correctly.

I demangled your function name here: https://demangler.com/

The C++ function has this signature

```
unsigned __int64 __cdecl ATCreateLoginRequest(
    unsigned __int64,
    wchar_t const *,
    wchar_t const *,
    void (__cdecl*)(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,struct _ATLOGIN_RESPONSE *)
)
```

Your delegate is therefore declared with the wrong calling convention. It should be:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void ATLoginResponseCallback(
    ulong hSession, 
    ulong hRequest, 
    ref ATLOGINRESPONSE response
);
```

Note that having changed `ATLOGINRESPONSE` to be a struct, we have to make the parameter a `ref` parameter.

The function `ATLoginResponseCallback` is declared correctly in your C# code.

Your other delegates will also need to be declared with `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`.

Unless the callback is only called from `ATCreateLoginRequest` then the delegate that is passed is subject to being garbage collected. So if `ATCreateLoginRequest` takes a copy of that delegate, and calls later, then you will need to keep the delegate alive. Assign it to a variable of type `ATLoginResponseCallback` whose life extends beyond the final call to the callback.

It's entirely plausible that the problems lie elsewhere.

Comment: David thanks for this information, I will dig into your answer.  Permissions is enum that's why I made it byte. Regarding class/struct - in same program I already had issue where it changing struct to class made things work.. That's why I initially uploaded my projects. It's simple 1 pages programs where C++ code is works properly, but c# is not. Pro dev can spot issue in 5 minutes..

Comment: If it's an enum, declare it as an enum. A byte array is certainly wrong.

Comment: sorry. from docs. typedef void(* ATLoginResponseCallback)(uint64_t session, uint64_t request, LPATLOGIN_RESPONSE pResponse)       where           typedef struct _ATLOGIN_RESPONSE * LPATLOGIN_RESPONSE                 where   ATLoginResponseType  loginResponse
 
uint8_t  permissions [255]
 
ATTIME  serverTime

Comment: I'm not going to do this in comments. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a place where we give you personalised help. We are here to create a resource of useful questions and answers. If you get helped along the way too then that's a happy side effect. Please edit the question to include the missing details.

Comment: I addeded _ATLOGIN_RESPONSE to original post. Changing my class to sruct and  declaration of delegate doesn't help

Comment: Now we can see how to declare the struct, mostly, see update. You don't seem to do much error checking in your code. Once you are confident that the p/invoke is right, you can look elsewhere for your problems. Don't be surprised if you have defects beyond the p/invoke ones. In other words, don't expect me to debug your entire program.

Comment: I'm a c# guy. All this is dark territory for me. I'm fighting this whole day, trying this and that. Reason why it first appear this way because I already had some move in this project and successefully  imported few similar functions. You could find glitch in my code for 5 minutes and get 150 reputation from me, not loosing hour. But thanks for education, it helps anyway.

Comment: Who cares about reputation? I think I've got enough. I'm here to help people learn. Are you interested in doing that?

Comment: Honestly I have huge field to learn and work in C#. I need to just import those 20 functions from this api and be happy to never get back to this C++ it's huge and complex universe not really needed for my goals.

Comment: Well, I've answered the question you asked I think.

Comment: Declaring it as a class is a workaround of sorts to get _ATLOGIN_RESPONSE* but requires [StructLayout].  Passing OnLoginResponseCallback is fatal syntax sugar, the delegate is not referenced anywhere and is going to be garbage collected.

Comment: so is  'ref ATLOGINRESPONSE response' is mistake in you answer? Tried everything beyond that. No problems should be with ATTIME struct it just uint16_t  year  uint16_t  month and so on. I use  public ushort year;...etc

Comment: The ref is needed after switching from class to struct.

Comment: reuploaded with all the changes. If someone will care to look

Comment: I can't download the project,,,,,

Comment: @ManKeer Even when you get the project it is incomplete because the dependent libraries are not included.

Comment: I'm very sorry guys. .Dll and .lib are in ATFeedConsole\Debug\ . I will try to set up relative paths in project. And I will add include Dir and reupload

Comment: Why don't you just do some debugging? Do you not know how to use the debugger?

Comment: reuploaded. Generally yes, I use it basic functionality. But it doesn't help me here. If debugger will be able to find a bug here and you'll give me a hint where to look I'll be very gratefull

Comment: Of course the debugger will help. Step through the code and see where it goes wrong. I can't believe you've not done that. How can you make progress without being able to debug?

Comment: I tried I'm telling you. I can see that ATSendRequest executes successfully, and OnLoginResponseCallback never fires. You can probably see my breakpoints. What else can I do?

Comment: What you could do is basic debugging. I won't attempt to teach you because you don't want to learn. I like to help people learn. You've stated repeatedly that you don't want to learn and you just want somebody to do your job for you for the reward of a small amount of rep.

Comment: I want to learn moreover it concerns debugging in .net which I do almost everyday. I just stated that I don't want to go deep into c++ as I'm not working with it and it huge topic.

Comment: You do realise that Hans said exactly the same as me. I'm afraid that the problem is that you've made no attempt to understand any of this. You changed the calling convention on one of the delegates, but left it as stdcall on the others? Do you know what a calling convention is? If not, shouldn't you? Your structs are still wrong. They are very easy to fix. You just have to understand what I wrote. Remember that you only showed part of the code. You have to apply what you learnt about those parts of the code to the rest of your code. Where else do you think you need to use `ByValArray`?

Comment: Thank you David. I admit I was very inattentive. I fixed byte array in ATGUID with ByValArray and now getting right login response type.  But the time I getting in ATLOGINRESPONSE still has crazy numbers, though it just struct with ushorts (uint16_t originally). I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: This question is over. I've made it clear what my views are. I'm interested in helping people learn. You don't want to learn. You made that clear with the bounty and the accept. You'll need to find somebody else to write your program with you. I cannot believe you have the gall to ask me for help again.

Comment: You should put the accept back to Hans. I don't want him to feel I took it from him.

Comment: Oh c'mon. I accepted it automatically with bounty award. I thought you said you don't care about rep. I can start new bounty and give it to you, just say.

Comment: No, I don't want a bounty, and I'd rather you accepted Hans' answer.

Comment: ATTIME struct was packed and there is no mention about it in documents and .h. By happy chance I googled into your answer in SO and Pack=1 helped. Can you imagine that?

Comment: I'm pleased that you are working at this yourself and learning. Well done.