# C# mono - passing stringbuilder to fill with unicode content in C++

Tags: c#, c++, mono, interop, marshalling

I have been struggling for a day now to get this work. It **works well on windows** but **not on Linux with mono**.

### What I am trying to achieve

**C# wrapper**

```
[DllImport("MyLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int MyFunction(StringBuilder str);

StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder(255);
var ret = MyFunction(myString);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}",myString.ToString());
```

**C++ shared lib (.dll or .so)**

```
WRAPPER_API int _stdcall MyFunction(wchar_t* str)
{
    wcscpy(str,L"this is a test");
    return 0;
}
```

### Results

Windows:

> Result: this is a test

Linux:

> Result: t

On mono the returned string contains only the **first character** of the string.
I tried with ANSI string changing wchar_t* to char* and wcscpy to strcpy and **it works**.

### My testing environment

```
Linux Ubuntu 32 bits 12.04 LTS / Mono 4.3.2
Windows 7 64 bits .Net 4.5
```

### Other questions and references

[How do I marshal wchar_t* from C++ to C# as an out parameter or return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089214/how-do-i-marshal-wchar-t-from-c-to-c-sharp-as-an-out-parameter-or-return-valu)

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#passing-caller-modifiable-strings

**Edit:**
Thanks to @Xanatos's answer I was able to solve my issue by using u16string (I have g++ 4.8.4 and enable c++11 standard):

```
WRAPPER_API int _stdcall MyFunction(chart16_t* str)
{
    u16string someString(u"some unicode string");
    someString.copy(str, someString.length());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope you copy-pasted wrongly: *[DllImport("MyLib.dll, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode")]* should be *"MyLib.dll", "CharSet*

Comment: @Iderache, I tested your Edit coming from Xanatos's answer and it does not work. Have you come up with a correct answer?Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with `wchar_t` in Linux: `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4` (while on Windows `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`). Sadly Mono on Linux/other Unix(es) doesn't do anything to solve it, and consider `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` everywhere (see for example http://mono-list.ximian.narkive.com/QzgsoSlk/support-for-marshalling-of-c-string-to-unmanaged-wchar-t-on-linux and http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/What-is-Correct-way-to-marshal-wchar-t-td1506090.html .)

There is no simple solution for this. If you are using newer C++ you can use `char16_t` with its functions [`std::char_traits<char16_t>::*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits).